# Discover and install network printers via powershell

Tags: powershell, printing, network-printers

I am new to PowerShell and I am trying to write a script that will install a series of network printers for me. To get me started I was looking for a way to find all shared printers on a print server and then install them locally. Here is something that doesn't work but gets the idea across. One thing to note is that this is this script is being run on a win 2008 server.

```
Get-WmiObject -computername $printServer -class Win32_Printer | Where {$_.name -notlike "Microsoft*"} | add-printer -connectionname \\$_.systemName\$_.shareName
```

Comment: You need `ForEach-Object` for `$_` to work in the pipeline. Replace the last command with `% { Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\$_.SystemName\$_.ShareName }` (`%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`) - untested. If this does not help, I'll try to play around with a vm and provide a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for the for each suggestion. I think there are two other pieces I have to figure out too (in addition to your for each tip). One is the concatenation of the string (I don't believe the way I did it will work). And second, the Add-Printer cmdlet does not seem to exist in server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have a way to test this but I believe that this may work for you.

```
$printClass = [wmiclass]"win32_printer"

Get-WmiObject -computername $printServer -class Win32_Printer | ? {$_.name -notlike "Microsoft*"} | % { $printClass.AddPrinterConnection([string]::Concat("\\", $_.systemName, "\", $_.shareName)) }
```